# RTK Query Error vs. Fetch for API Call to Open Weather

Tags: react-native, api, fetch-api, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm dealing with a super annoying issue that I have not been able to resolve for several hours. I am trying to fetch an API from open weather and I've gotten it to work by simply putting the URL into google, and I've gotten it working with the fetch command built into React, but would really like to use RTK Query. I followed the guidelines for RTK Query to the T and my API call keeps returning undefined. Here is my API Code:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const weatherApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'weatherApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getWeather: builder.query({
        query: (lat, long, units) => `lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=${units}&APPID=API_KEY_HERE`,
      }),
    }),
  })
  
  // Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
  // auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
  export const { useGetWeatherQuery } = weatherApi
```

My redux store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query'
import { weatherApi } from './api'


export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [weatherApi.reducerPath]: weatherApi.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  getDefaultMiddleware().concat(weatherApi.middleware),
})

setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

API call in code:

```
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetWeatherQuery('29.7','-95','Imperial')
  console.log(data)
```

RETURNS 'undefined'
ALSO tried many combinations of inputs:

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetWeatherQuery({lat: 29.7,long: -95,units: 'Imperial'})
```

I'll take this exact same API URL and paste it in google, or through the fetch command and it works perfectly, spits out the results immediately:

```
  const fetchWeatherData = async (lat, long) => {
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=${units}&APPID=`, {
      "headers": {
        "x-api-key": API_KEY_HERE
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

If someone can tell me what is wrong with my Redux statement, I would love you forever.... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, and lots of research online, I was able to get it to work for those who need it:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

// Define a service using a base URL and expected endpoints
export const weatherApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'weatherApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getWeather: builder.query({
        query: (arg) => {
          const { lat, long, units} = arg;
          const newURL = `lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=${units}&APPID=API_KEY_HERE`,
          return newURL;
      }),
    }),
  })
  
  // Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
  // auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
  export const { useGetWeatherQuery } = weatherApi
```

And then calling it like so:

```
const { data , error, isLoading, isSuccess } = useGetWeatherQuery({lat: '29.7', long: '-95', units: 'Metric'})
```

Essentially RTKQuery only takes one argument, so you have to enter it as one argument and then de-structure it.

Comment: This is basically right, but you don't have to create the whole query string yourself.  You can `return { url: '/', params: { lat, lon, units, APPID: API_KEY_HERE } }`.  If you do this then you need to remove the trailing `?` from your `baseUrl` (so it ends with `weather` not `weather?`). [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#setting-the-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

It is very normal that that would return `undefined` for a while - after all, that data needs to travel through the internet to your computer, which can take a few seconds on a bad connection. In the meantime, nothing stops your component from rendering, though. React doesn't pause (unless you use Suspense, which at this point is still experimental for that kind of things).

That's why you always have to check `isLoading`, or even better: `isSuccess`, before you can access `data`. In the first few renders you might need to render a loading indicator instead of doing actual logic with `data`.

Comment: I tried adding if (!isLoading) { console.log(data) } still undefined. The more reading I'm doing, the more I'm realizing that RTK query doesn't accept multiple parameters very well.  https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1028

Comment: I didn't even see that. Yes, you have to put in exactly one argument, you can combine everything in an object like you showed.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your network tab to see a request go out, and if it's the right request/response?